# Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in C:\Users\me\project\index.php on line 4

Tags: php, heroku, xampp

Working on Facebook app, set up on Heroku, used git to download their code, using xampp for apache web server. Had to set xampp to listen on a different port because :80 is taken, so changed httpd.conf to Listen 8080 and added virtual hosts so I could set up the facebook environment variables as per the Heroku facebook application requires. In order to get apache to run without errors, found websites stating that I also had to change the port for SSL in httpd-ssl.conf. I changed this to 4430 based on another website's recommendation. Apache/xampp starts up fine now, but I get error messages from the Facebook Heroku code when I go to it (same errors whether via apps.facebook.com/myapp or directly at localhost:8080) errors follow:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in C:\Users\me\project\index.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in C:\Users\me\project\AppInfo.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in C:\Users\me\project\AppInfo.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: access_token in C:\Users\me\project\FBUtils.php on line 108
```

Top line of the first file where the problem starts:

```
<?php

// Enforce https on production
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == "http" && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1' && $_SE    RVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'localhost') {

  header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

  exit();

}
```

Note that this code was provided by Heroku/GitHub when setting up a Facebook App on their platform. There seems to be quite a few bugs in it beyond the ones I listed.

Comment: (Referencing an answer from another thread) It looks like you do not have cURL functions installed. Run a php_info() file and check for any mention of cURL functions. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874425/500-error-developing-heroku-php-facebook-app-locally

Answer (score 7):

This error says that key `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` does not exist in $_SERVER array.
If you want to escape such errors you have to check if such key exists in array example:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == "http" && ...)
```

or use [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) method like this:

```
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO') == "http" && getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') != '127.0.0.1' && getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') != 'localhost')
```

Comment: Good idea, but if you look at my code provided you can see that all indices are within single or double quotes including HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO.

Comment: Thanks. The isset is a good idea, but there seem to be too many errors with this program from Heroku/GitHub. I think I will use a different code base for a facebook app. THANK YOU!

Comment: If anyone is using this code, here's the original code: https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php (pulled Jan 11, 2012)  here's some help: http://mantisforge.org/dev/gitstats/commit-detail.php?commit=e918599783875090a446c3fe8aeebec8d0f1f817   
Then do this for all undefined indices, then still end up with "Invalid Credentials" after all that! So what I recommend is looking at something else for a code base like: http://phpmaster.com/integrating-with-facebook/   or   http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/